# Find JSON Object using multiple key/value pairs, then update that Object's other attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Given

```
sessionStorage.cart = "[
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":1,"specification":""},
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":2,"specification":""},       
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":3,"specification":""}
]"
```

I'd like to write a function that finds the object with id of 121, name of Pants, number of 2, so that I can update that object's specification. So I would pass the id, the name, the number, and the desired new specification value, and get an output of this:

```
sessionStorage.cart = "[
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":1,"specification":""},
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":2,"specification":"new value"},       
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":3,"specification":""}
]"
```

Am really struggling on thinking this one through... guidance welcome!

Comment: Try to start with `for` and `if`

Comment: The question is using an array in the example, not JSON which is making the answers below incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```js
var cart = [
    {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "Pants",
        "number": 1,
        "specification": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "Pants",
        "number": 2,
        "specification": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "Pants",
        "number": 3,
        "specification": ""
    }
];

cart.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.id == 121 && entry.name == 'Pants' && entry.number == 2) {
        entry.specification = 'new value';
    }
});

console.log(cart);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
sessionStorage.cart.find(e => 
  e.id     === 121     &&
  e.name   === 'Pants' &&
  e.number === 2
).specification = 'new value';

console.log(JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.cart, null, '  '));
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "id": 121,
    "name": "Pants",
    "number": 1,
    "specification": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 121,
    "name": "Pants",
    "number": 2,
    "specification": "new value"
  },
  {
    "id": 121,
    "name": "Pants",
    "number": 3,
    "specification": ""
  }
]
```

Note: This requires ES6.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this code:

```
function update(oldValues, newValues, keyToCompare) {
    var keyToCompareLen = keyToCompare.length;
    var result = [];
    oldValues.forEach(function(oldValue){

        newValues.forEach(function(newValue){
            var cnt = 0;
            keyToCompare.forEach(function(key){
                if(newValue[key] == oldValue[key]) {
                    ++cnt;
                }
            });

            if(cnt == keyToCompareLen) {
                oldValue = $.extend(true, {}, oldValue, newValue);
            }
        });

        result.push(oldValue);
    });

    return result;
}

var result = update([
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":1,"specification":""},
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":2,"specification":""},       
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":3,"specification":""}
], [
  {"id":121,"name":"Pants","number":2,"specification":"test"}
], [
  "id",
  "name",
  "number"
]);

console.log(result);
```

Note: You need to include the jquery library. You can also run the code here https://fiddle.jshell.net/b17fx6qk/1/

Comment: I think it's a little over to use jQuery for only `jQuery.extend()` method while you don't use it in other places.

Comment: @iplus26, No problem to that because he/she is already using a jquery library.

Comment: No, no, no. Don't get me wrong. I just want to discuss when to use jQuery... It's nothing personal, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through an array can be inefficient. For performance, you could stringify all of your index values and use them to store your objects in a hashmap for a quick lookup. Something like:

```
function cartItem() {
  this.id;
  this.name;
  this.number;
  this.specification;
}

CartItem.hash = function(id, name, number) {
  return [id, name, number].join('|');
};

cartItem.prototype.toHash = function() {
  return CartItem.hash(this.id, this.name, this.number);
};

var cartMap = cart.reduce(function(map, item) {
  var key = item.toHash();
  map[key] = item;
}, { });
```

Then you can (very quickly) look the item up by its hash:

```
cartMap[CartItem.hash(id, name, number)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. Simply match and update

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var o = [];
  o.id = 121;
  o.name = "Pants";
  o.number = 2;

  updateVal(o);

});


function updateVal(o) {

  var cart = [{
    "id": 121,
    "name": "Pants",
    "number": 1,
    "specification": ""
  }, {
    "id": 121,
    "name": "Pants",
    "number": 2,
    "specification": ""
  }, {
    "id": 121,
    "name": "Pants",
    "number": 3,
    "specification": ""
  }];

  $.each(cart, function(a, b) {

    if (b.id == o.id && b.name == o.name && b.number == o.number) {
      b.specification = "new value";
    }


  });

  alert("value updated. specification:" + cart[1].specification);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```