# Angular JS splice items from the Response based on two parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my JSON response . I am able to splice out elements from controller side using something like this . Now comes a situation where my employees can have same employee id but different Type . So i would like to remove itesm from the response by comparing both Id & type. For example I need to remove the emplooyee with Id ABC and type D only . How can i splice them out how can i proceed

```
var searchresponse = [{
    "items": [{
        "employeeId": "ABC",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "ABC",
        "type": "P",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "NPK",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "PKN",
        "type": "A",
        "alive": "Yes"
    }],
    "more": false
}];

var data1 = ["ABC"];
var data2 = ["D"] //- how to splice ABC also comparing the D 
var items = searchresponse[0].items;
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (data1.indexOf(items[i].employeeId) != -1) {
        items.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "items": [{
        "employeeId": "ABC",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }] do you need a reponse like this ?

Comment: I have an Response like that .. I need to splice out that particular id ABC from the Search response

Comment: Can you simply iterate over the response? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868918/find-json-object-using-multiple-key-value-pairs-then-update-that-objects-other Do a foreach and check the values

Answer (score 1):

If i understand u right.. will it be ok to just extend the if clause?

`if (data1.indexOf(items[i].employeeId) != -1  && data2.indexOf(items[i].type) != -1)`

Comment: I should have tried this before posting it :) it worked !!

Answer (score 1):

Using  [array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

```
 var filterd =searchresponse[0].items.filter(function (item) {
 return item.employeeId == "ABC"&& item.type== "D"
})
```

You may Also use underscore.js simple javascript library in your case

```
var filterd=_.where(searchresponse[0].items, {employeeId: "ABC", type: "D"});
```

will give you

```
 [{
    "employeeId": "ABC",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}]
```

[Check this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7jtwnwv/1/)