# Filtering JSON data for multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, json

I am quite new to coding and kind of stuck with the following issue.

My JSON data looks like this:

```js
var data = [
 {
  "location_name": "Training Club",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Fitness",
  "postcode": "1094"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Boxing Center",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Martial Arts",
  "postcode": "1096AN"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Boxing Center 2",
  "Area Code": "F",
  "location_type": "Martial Arts",
  "postcode": "1096AN"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "DanceDance",
  "Area Code": "A",
  "location_type": "Dance",
  "postcode": "1093JX"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "CrossFit Box",
  "Area Code": "A",
  "location_type": "CrossFit",
  "postcode": "1019AJ"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Gym A",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Fitness",
  "postcode": "1098NJ"
 }, ]//and so  on.....
```

I fetch input from a form via a webhook and get the following results:

Area Code = "C"
sport_type = "Fitness"

So now I want to search/filter my data for all options with both Area Code 'C' and Fitness.

This code would only give me the very first result of the list:

```js
search = JSON.search(inputData.area_code === 'C');
console.log(search);
var C = JSON.search(data[0]);

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {    
    console.log(data[i]);
};
 
output = {search};
```

Does someone have an idea to solve this?
Cheers,
Nicole

Comment: What is `JSON.search`? Are you using a library?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868918/find-json-object-using-multiple-key-value-pairs-then-update-that-objects-other

Answer (score 2):

Use filter function and specify your condition as && operand

```
data.filter(function(el){
         return (el["Area Code"] == "C" && el.location_type == "Fitness"); 
      });
```

```js
var data = [
 {
  "location_name": "Training Club",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Fitness",
  "postcode": "1094"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Boxing Center",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Martial Arts",
  "postcode": "1096AN"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Boxing Center 2",
  "Area Code": "F",
  "location_type": "Martial Arts",
  "postcode": "1096AN"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "DanceDance",
  "Area Code": "A",
  "location_type": "Dance",
  "postcode": "1093JX"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "CrossFit Box",
  "Area Code": "A",
  "location_type": "CrossFit",
  "postcode": "1019AJ"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Gym A",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Fitness",
  "postcode": "1098NJ"
 }]

   var s = data.filter(function(el){
     return (el["Area Code"] == "C" && el.location_type == "Fitness"); 
  });

  console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) method using `ES6` Arrow function.**

```js
var data = [
 {
  "location_name": "Training Club",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Fitness",
  "postcode": "1094"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Boxing Center",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Martial Arts",
  "postcode": "1096AN"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Boxing Center 2",
  "Area Code": "F",
  "location_type": "Martial Arts",
  "postcode": "1096AN"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "DanceDance",
  "Area Code": "A",
  "location_type": "Dance",
  "postcode": "1093JX"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "CrossFit Box",
  "Area Code": "A",
  "location_type": "CrossFit",
  "postcode": "1019AJ"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Gym A",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Fitness",
  "postcode": "1098NJ"
 }];
  
  var res = data.filter(item => { return item["Area Code"] == "C" && item["location_type"] == "Fitness" });
  
console.log(res);
```

**2. using JavaScript [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop :**

```js
var data = [
 {
  "location_name": "Training Club",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Fitness",
  "postcode": "1094"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Boxing Center",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Martial Arts",
  "postcode": "1096AN"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Boxing Center 2",
  "Area Code": "F",
  "location_type": "Martial Arts",
  "postcode": "1096AN"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "DanceDance",
  "Area Code": "A",
  "location_type": "Dance",
  "postcode": "1093JX"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "CrossFit Box",
  "Area Code": "A",
  "location_type": "CrossFit",
  "postcode": "1019AJ"
 },
 {
  "location_name": "Gym A",
  "Area Code": "C",
  "location_type": "Fitness",
  "postcode": "1098NJ"
 }];
  
var result = [];  
for (var i in data) {
  if(data[i]["Area Code"] == "C" && data[i]["location_type"] == "Fitness") {
    result.push(data[i]);
  }
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Used the 1st proposal and it works perfectly with some adjustments! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please mark it as correct so that it will be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mention, you can use filter to prune out the results. I would advice you use triple equals as it it best practice:

```
var result = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item["Area Code"] === "C" && item["location_type"] === "Fitness";
});
```

A more modern syntax would be:

```
let result = data.filter(item => item["Area Code"] === "C" && item["location_type"] === "Fitness");
```

You can also do it using a loop, and even if performance is slightly better, it's not as readable:

```
var data = [ ... ];
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {    
    if (data[i]["Area Code"] === "C" && data[i]["location_type"] === "Fitness") {
        result.push(data[i]);
    }
};
```